# Syntax question for adding a % sign in output

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tried leveraging some solutions I have seen here into my own query, but cannot seem to get it right without an error. I am using BigQuery on Google's SQL site. Maybe there is a limitation there? My code looks like,

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(
    (
       SELECT
          (AVG (ridership_2016) + AVG (ridership_2017) + AVG (ridership_2018)) / 3 
       FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present
      WHERE station_name = 'Atlantic Av - Barclays Ctr'
    ) / (AVG (ridership_2016) + AVG (ridership_2017) + AVG (ridership_2018)) AS FLOAT64), 2) * 100
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present;
```

The above code successfully outputs 37.0, but I cannot seem to get the VARCHAR conversion function to work, so I can add + '' + '%'  at the end of the 37.0.

Is it maybe better to do this as a CTE and use a CONCAT query to add in the % symbol?

Comment: Wrap that monstrosity in `CONCAT(CAST(<monstrosity> AS STRING), '%')` should do the trick, I believe.

Comment: just add `|| '%'` to the end of select statement (right before `from` . no needs in explicit casting here ...

Comment: Thank you so much! 'monstrosity' lol

Both ways worked! @JNevill I did not have to use 'AS STRING' - just ,'%' in the CONCAT wrap. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT ROUND(100 * 
  AVG(IF(station_name = 'Atlantic Av - Barclays Ctr', (ridership_2016 + ridership_2017 + ridership_2018) / 3, null)) /
  AVG (ridership_2016 + ridership_2017 + ridership_2018), 2) || "%"
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present;
```

with output

[image]